# Vertical grid with EXT JS

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I want to use the EXT JS's Grid panel to show some data, but I want something like this :

**First name** Foo

**Last name** Bar

**Age** 18

**Country** US

rather than :

**First name** **Last name** **Age** **Country**

Foo Bar 18 US

Assuming that there will be only one record.

What I have in mind is loop through the records and create a new table having each row containing a specific information. Something like :

```
[
  ['First name', 'Foo']
  ['Last name', 'Bar']
   ...
]
```

but I want to know if there is a better solution/approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [property grid](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.property.Grid)